# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, incorrectly-closed

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613723/how-can-i-install-apk-on-android-avd) is from a user who is struggling using the android debugger tools on Ubuntu.

Why is this off-topic? This isn't an android problem, this is a "how to do x on Ubuntu" problem where "x" just happens to be related to android...

It's even answered...

Comment: Agreed. The issue seems to be on the Ubuntu side, not Android. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Agreed. I voted to close because it was unclear what he was asking, which made it look like it wasn't about Ubuntu. His [original question](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/613723/1) was not clear. I've voted to reopen again.